# C# WMI Process Restarter

Tags: c#, process, wmi

#### Scenario

I have a bunch of processes running on a server as part of various C# Applications.
Occasionally some of these crash for whatever reason (old legacy code that I don't currently have the time to replace or refactor).

#### Idea

I want to create a C# Service that continually checks to see if these processes are running, and if not, restart them.

#### Questions

Someone mentioned WMI? - And something about there being a C# wrapper for this?
Something that essentially lets you write.

```
   Processes.GetProcessByName("MyProcess");
```

any help, advice, suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

I've seen an example of something that restarts Services, and it uses WindowsIdentity to impersonate a user, logon to a server and restart the services....Something similar would be fantastic, although I'm not sure how to even go about implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public static Process GetProcessByName(string processName)
{  
    return Process
             .GetProcesses()
             .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName == processName);
}
```

Something like that?